# Fourier transform of Majorana operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, fourier-transform, many-body, ising-model

The Ising model in terms of Majorana operators can be written as
\begin{equation}
H=iJ\sum_{j=1} ^{L-1} a_j b_{j+1}+ih\sum_{i=1} ^{L} a_j b_j
\end{equation}
where $a_j$ and $b_j$ are the Majorana operators.

I am trying to diagonalize the above model and the convention of Fourier transform which I am using is

$$a_j=\sqrt{4/L}\sum_{k\space \epsilon \space \frac{Bz}{2}} a_k \space e^{ik.j}  +  a_k ^{\dagger} \space e^{-ik.j}$$
which is given in Eq.4 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.4701

My question is why in the above equations they are summing over half the Brillouin zone and not the full Brillouin zone from $\{-\pi, \pi\}$?

Also when I try to diagonalize Ising model using above convention I get
$$H=\sum_{k,\alpha} \epsilon_\alpha(k)c^\dagger_{k,\alpha}c_{k,\alpha}$$
band spectrum form which I get is $\epsilon(k)=\sqrt{1+2hCos[k]+h^2}$ whereas in the literature the form of band spectrum given is $\epsilon(k)=\sqrt{1-2hCos[k]+h^2}$.

Can somebody help me why I am getting a different band spectrum? and Is the above Fourier transform convention right?